# Often(but not always) after using the git log command, : are shown on my terminal window and it just becomes unresponsive

Tags: git, pager

I tried searching on the web and here on Stackoverflow but can't seem to find a similar problem/ solution. I'm not exactly sure on how to word this problem, so i've added an image link. I get this problem often but not always-after using the ' git log'  command. When I try to close the  terminal, the error dialogue box pops up.

[image: Image 1: Screenshot of the terminal screen. I can't type anything after the : at the very bottom]

Image 1: Screenshot of the terminal screen. I can't type anything after the : at the very bottom

[image: Image 2: Error dialogue box pop-up when I try to close the terminal]

Image 2: Error dialogue box pop-up when I try to close the terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a sign of `pager`. You can disable it by `git config --global core.pager ""` for good, or `git -c core.pager="" log` or `git --no-pager log` for once.

But it's not a good idea to disable it in case the output is lengthy. When you see ":", you can press q to quit, or press arrow keys, page up, page down to navigate the output. Input `/keyword` and press enter to search the output for the keyword.

Besides, you can use the options like `-3`, `--oneline` to limit the output of `git log`.

The `less` in the 2nd image is one of the pagers. It's the default pager Git uses.